# How can I add space to a partition which is not the last?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, vmware

I have an Ubuntu Server virtualized (version 
Linux server 3.2.0-58-generic #88-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux) in a VMWare, like this:

hard Disk1 SCSI(0:0) --> 11 Gb   /dev/sda1
hard disk2 SCSI(0:1) --> 30 Gb   /dev/sdb1

This machine has this occupation:

**fdiks-l**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 11.8 GB, 11811160064 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1435 cylinders, total 23068672 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0001ce75

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    15958015     7977984   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        15960062    16775167      407553    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        15960064    16775167      407552   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 32.2 GB, 32212254720 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3916 cylinders, total 62914560 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2666a626

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              63    41961779    20980858+  83  Linux
/dev/sdb2        41961780    62910539    10474380   83  Linux
```

So, my objective is:

1. Create spce in Vmware to HD2 (SCSI(0:1))
2. Give that space to /var (/dev/sdb1)

My free space is:
**df -k**

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       8,1G  6,7G  944M  88% /
udev            3,2G  4,1k  3,2G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1,3G  500k  1,3G   1% /run
none            5,3M     0  5,3M   0% /run/lock
none            3,2G     0  3,2G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sdb1        22G   19G  1,3G  94% /var
/dev/sdb2        11G  7,4G  2,8G  73% /home
```

I'm reading things like [this](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/extending-partitions-on-linux-vmware-virtual-machines/), but I guess that I can't resize /dev/sdb1 (/var) if I had /dev/sdb2 (/home) just next door, the last block of sdb1 is the next in sdb2.. What are my options? I thinking in:

1. Merge sdb1 and sdb2
2. Add space to this new partition
3. Split again /var and /home, but leave the maximum space to /var

But I don't know... All of this, without loss any data... any ideas?

Comment: Add a new virtual disk and move `/var` onto it.

Answer (score 2):

You should back up before any solution because any solution comes with risk.

You have a lot of options, depending on how costly downtime is/disk space/doing it right/future proofing.

1. The simplest option might be to create a new partition at the end of /sdb and mount it to where you need the additional space. Using symlinks can help you move multiple directories behind it. Very little, if any, downtime, and no moving data arround. Moving /home onto a new /dev/sdb3 is not that hard - just (without anyone other then you being able to access /home while moving) mount /dev/sdb3 in a new place, move /home to the new partition, unmount it, edit /etc/fstab to mount the new disk at /home. -Problem is it's wasteful because it does not share space between /home and the rest of the system.
2. You may be able to merge and demerge data as you suggest, but you may also be able to use gparted to move the partition. I expect it would take a while though.
3. You could rebuild the VM "better" using LVM - which will allow you a lot more flexibility to add disks and resize block devices in the future. Unfortunately converting to LVM is non-trivial, and likely means rebuilding the VM.

Comment: I'll try option 1, looks like the simplest solution, like you said.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[Davidgo's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1303252/432690) is good. Yet another option: use [Btrfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs).

1. In theory [you can convert](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Conversion_from_Ext3) from *unmounted* ext3/ext4 to Btrfs in place:

   ```
   fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sdb1
   btrfs-convert /dev/sdb1
   ```

   In practice you should backup your data beforehand anyway.
2. Adjust your `fstab` so it works with Btrfs and `/var` mounts just fine.
3. Create a new partition or maybe a separate device, whatever suits you.
4. [Add the new partition/device](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices#Adding_new_devices) to your (mounted) Btrfs filesystem:

   ```
   btrfs device add /dev/sdb3 /var   # (partition)
   # or
   btrfs device add /dev/sdc /var    # (entire device)
   ```